# Java- How can you close `FileInputStream` in finally block if the same method returns that `FileInputStream`

Tags: java, sonarqube, fileinputstream, autocloseable

`Sonar` is showing a bug for the below code which is of blocker type. It's complaining that I have not closed `FileInputStream` but how can I do that? `FileInputStream` is the return type of method and if I close here then it will be of no use from where it's calling. Please let me know- how can I close `FileInputStream` in finally block if the same method returns that `FileInputStream`?

**Here is the code:**

```
@Override
public InputStream getInputStream() throws MissingObjectException {

    try {
        InputStream is;
        if (smbFile != null) {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(new SmbFileInputStream(smbFile), 60000);
        } 
        else {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(getFilePath()));
        }
        return is;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MissingObjectException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste your code in the question in text form with proper formatting.

Comment: @Antoniossss and he said that. He does not want to close it, he express wondering why IDE is complaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to close the input in the same function. The problem may be that you should not declare `InputStream is` in `try{}` block as well as putting the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Put is declaration before try block

```
 InputStream is= null;
try {
    if (smbFile != null) {
        is = new BufferedInputStream(new SmbFileInputStream(smbFile), 60000);             } else {
        is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(getFilePath()));
    }
    return is;
}
catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MissingObjectException();
}finally{
  if(is !=null){
  is.close();
 }
}
```